# Hibernate Result Transformer not working for Critera.scroll

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Entity `ObjA` has a One-To-Many relationship with another entity `ObjB`.

The following code in my dao works as expected:

```
Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ObjA);
//......
criteria.setReadOnly(true);
criteria.setCacheable(false);
criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
List<ObjA> results = criteria.list();
```

To optimize above code (to avoid OutOfMemoryException), I tried using ScrollableResults instead of `criteria.list()`:

```
//same as above code..
ScrollableResults results = criteria.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
while(results.next()){
    ObjA a = results.get()[0];
    session.evict(a); 
    //store 'a' in a collection
}
```

However, using this approach, I ended up getting individual rows for each `ObjB` corresponding to `ObjA` (in a sense, duplicate root entities). I tried *not* evicting the entity, but still got duplicate rows.

Any idea what I am doing wrong/missing here?

P.S. Hibernate version - 3.5.1-FINAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a never-ending bug/required enhancement in hibernate.
I ended up using `fetch="select"` for all one-to-many joins.

Although this increased the db queries, but removed the duplicate root entities.